# Django lockdown logout

Tags: python, html, django, logout, lockdown

Im trying to logout of my lockdown session. In the docs it says

> LOCKDOWN_LOGOUT_KEY
>
> A key which, if provided in the query string of a locked URL, will log out the user from the preview.

I'm not sure if I understand it rightly. I tried to implement this like this:

1. I have the lockdown middleware in the middleware list.
2. I have these lockdown options in settings.py:

```html
LOCKDOWN_FORM = 'lockdown.forms.AuthForm'
LOCKDOWN_AUTHFORM_STAFF_ONLY = False
LOCKDOWN_LOGOUT_KEY = 'logout'
```

3. I have a button which links to "/logout/"

```html
<form action="/logout/">
  <input type="submit" value="Logout"/>
</form>
```

4. This just links to a HttpResponseRedirect() back to my main page:

**urls.py:**

```html
path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout')
```

**views.py:**

```html
def logout(request):
 return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

The link works and takes me back to my main page.
But the logout doesn't occure.
Does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT:
I found a solution.
I added one line of code to the logout function in views.py:

```html
def logout(request):
  request.session.flush()
  return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
I added one line of code to the logout function in views.py:

```html
def logout(request):
  request.session.flush()
  return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the value of `LOCKDOWN_LOGOUT_KEY` ("preview-logout" by default) as a query string parameter.

```
<a href="/?preview-logout">Log out</a>
```